# Can we have revision updates for Careers?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I know that for normal Stack Overflow codebase changes, we're not usually notified of the small things; and the big things are usually put into a blog post.

That works quite well, since we're not paying for that service -- there's no real need for us to be aware of any change.

Not so with Careers, however.  We **are** paying for that service, and changes in how it works may lead us to change or update our CV.

Can we request a blog post or a meta post (or even something on the careers site itself) from the team of changes made for Careers so that we're kept up to date? I suppose it could be solved by doing a tag search for **`[careers] [status-completed]`**, but that's an indirect way to keep up with it.

Comment: Oh, you're paying for SOFU alright. But not with money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our strategy here is to send fairly regular emails to our paying customers, letting them know what's going on. You should have gotten one of these already.

Comment: Are we going to get an update with the careers update that were made?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever changes of relative importance have been made they have always made it fairly well known using the status completed tags and via blog posts. I don't see why that would change at all with the careers section.

Comment: I think of it like changes that were made to the UI field -- unless you knew to look for them, you had no idea that the date UI format 'changed'.  I may not know to troll meta for updates for Careers; but if I'm paying for the careers service, you can bet your bottom dollar I'm going to keep up with the careers.stackoverflow.com updates from that site.  Wheaties and cornpuffs and all that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great idea.

I only recently found, solely by looking through the questions on meta surrounding careers that the number of tags you can stick on as your `Favorite` (and others) has been increased to 10.

Ideally I'd have been notified of that change.

Answer (score 1):

Great idea - things have been a bit hectic with Dev Days going on, so our head blogger has been swamped.

We'll discuss exposing our source control commit messages<sup>*</sup> for Careers; you could then get every delicious change we make!

<sub>Note to self: no more flippant remarks in my messages :)</sub>

Comment: I can see those commit messages: Commit: I HATE GEORGE (Oh, and fixed formatting).